# Laravel 4 Many to Many update

Tags: php, database, many-to-many, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm stuck in a problem and I can't find a solution to this, it's annoying me.

I've two tables, one called *contacts* and the other one called *phonebooks* and they are linked with a third table called *contacts_phonebooks*, this is a many-to-many relationship summarize below:

- contacts: id (pk)
- phonebooks: id (pk)
- contacts_phonebooks: contactid (fk), phonebooksid (fk)
  Pretty simple and clear, and it works.

I'm using Laravel 4 and Eloquent ORM, everythings works fine when I've to fetch it, insert it and delete it but when I need to update a contact I fail miserably. I've a form that has a number of checkboxes that represent all the phonebooks (every checkbox has phonebook[] as name) so when you check one of those the phonebook id will be saved in the *contacts_phonebooks* with the contact id.
The problem is that this is not true! I mean when I run this code:

```
$contact = Contact::find($id);
$contact->contact_name = Input::get('newCName');
$contact->contact_surname = Input::get('newCSurname');
$contact->contact_email = Input::get('newCEmail');
$contact->contact_phone = Input::get('newCPhone');
$contact->contact_birth = Input::get('newCDate');
$contact->phonebooks()->sync(Input::get('phonebook'));
if($contact->save())
{
    return "TEST DONE?";
}
```

It deletes every row in *contacts_phonebooks* associated with the contact id and save only the new one checked... This is weird I know, I try to explain it better.
I want to update Mr.x and he actually is in "Stackoverflow" phonebook, I want to add him in "Nerd" phonebook so I click on update and I selected "Nerd", the other one is already selected.

When I update him the system deletes the "Stackoverflow" link and save ONLY the "Nerd" phonebook (with the code above) this things driving me crazy because Laravel 4 Doc says that you should use the *sync()* method in order to update a many-to-many relationship.

I don't how how to solve it, I hope you will understand what's my problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says "The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table. After this operation is complete, only the IDs in the array will be on the intermediate table for the model:"

So what I think you are probably looking for is `attach()`.

`$contact->phonebooks()->attach(Input::get('phonebook'));`

Then you will have to use `detach()` to remove him from the other.

Comment: It seems a bit weird but it works ... the process flow is that I've to use every time $contact->phonebooks()->detach() and then $contact->phonebooks()->attach(Input::get('phonebook'))

Comment: In that case, you are giving the sync wrong parameters.  Check our this test code I've created.  http://paste.laravel.com/F3b

Comment: The foreign keys on that pivot table migration should be integers but it doesn't really matter too much apparently since it did still work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models): The `sync` method accepts an array of IDs to place on the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Your pivot table should be named
    `contact_phonebook`
and it specifies that in Laravel's documentation.